# How to import a class' function to another .py in the same directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Forgive me, I am new to coding in Python and trying to learn the basics...
I am trying to import classA's function "functionA" into classB to use the function. For example:

```
class classA():
   def functionA():
      print("Jello World!")
```

Now I have this on one .py, let's say it's called "sampleA.py" in the same directory called "directory". Now the question is, how do I make it so I can use classA's function "functionA" in classB and have classB on another file called "sampleB.py" in the same directory.

I am so sorry if this is confusing but I want to figure out how to make it so, it's something like:

```
class classB():
   classA.functionA()
```

And this would print "Jello World!"

Comment: `from sampleA import classA`? And then you can just do `functionA = classA.functionA` in your `classB` definition.

Comment: @kindall I tried that but I get the error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'classA'"

Comment: It works. Hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Do you want a function or a method? Did your code compile? This code won't work, because you always have to add self (`def functionA(self):`) at the definition.

Comment: @cpt.Complex did you run it? It works using function like classmethod: `classA.functionA()`

Comment: @cpt.Complex technically you don't need the `self` in the parameters. I just ran it without and it outputs "Jello World!" correctly. I'm not saying it has no side-effects, but it does run.

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov thank you for pointing that out, I ran it without @ staticmethod and it didn't work, but with the annotation everything was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, like this:

```
from sampleA import classA
```

You can now call `functionA` like this:

```
classA.functionA()
```

Using your code:

**sampleA.py**

```
class classA():
   def functionA():
      print("Jello World!")
```

**sampleB.py**

```
from sampleA import classA

class classB():
    def __init__(self):
        classA.functionA()
```

I added an `__init__` function to `classB` so `functionA` gets executed immediately. Important caveat: `sampleA.py` and `sampleB.py` **must** be in the same directory.

Comment: This worked, what I was doing wrong was I was pulling from the directory and not the .py itself, so it was "from directory import classA" FailFish, thank you so much!